# Blog website with Rails and React: Trying to send a fetched object to another component

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails

I been trying to send a fetched object to a different component in React. Therefore, I been trying to send the object as a prop to the component that I'm trying to send it to. However, I'm not sure how to apply that in my code.

This is my component called "postContainer":

```
export default function postContainer({post}){

function handleDelete(){
    fetch(`/post/${post.id}`,{
        method: "DELETE",
        headers: {
            'Content-Type':'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(post)
    })
    .then((r) => r.json())
    .then(console.log("Post Removed"))
    window.location.reload();
}

function handleUpdate(){
  // I don't know what to do from here.
}

return(
    <div className='postContainer'>
        <h1>{post.title}</h1>
        <p className="users-posts-content">{post.content}</p>
        <p>{post.tags}</p>
        <button onClick={handleUpdate}>Update</button>
        <button onClick={handleDelete}>Delete Post</button>
    </div>
)}
```

This code above basically stores individual post in a certain look like the one that is circled (In short, I used mass assignment to show individual data that is from my rails backend):
[Frontend design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/45Ocy.png)

If a user press "Update" button, it should send the selected post data to a different component called "Update.js" as a prop.

```
export default function Update({post}){
return(
    <>
    // I didn't add anything yet. Trying to get the data from my "postContainer.js"
    </>
)
```

}

So that the user can go and edit the post with new information in "Update.js" component. I'm not sure how to accomplish that in my situation. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set a state and render the component conditionally according to the state value, and set the state when the component needs to be rendered.

Import Update Component in **postContainer**

Something like this

```
import Update  from './Update';

export default function postContainer({post}){
const [loadDeleteComponent, setLoadDeleteComponent] = useState(false);

function handleDelete(){
    fetch(`/post/${post.id}`,{
        method: "DELETE",
        headers: {
            'Content-Type':'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(post)
    })
    .then((r) => r.json())
    .then(console.log("Post Removed"))
    window.location.reload();
}

return(
    <div className='postContainer'>
      <h1>{post.title}</h1>
      <p className="users-posts-content">{post.content}</p>
      <p>{post.tags}</p>
      <button onClick={() => setLoadDeleteComponent(true)}>Update</button>
      {loadDeleteComponent && (
        <Update
          post={ post }
        />
      )}
    </div>
)}
```

trigger edit call from Update component.